# iOS CollectionView: Display View, then download images, then display images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view, which contains cells in each section, and each cell has an image in it.

Possibly, the collection view holds 20 or more cells.

I want to load the images off the internet into the cells. The issue is that this can take a few seconds, and I want the collectionView to be displayed even if the images have not downloaded completely.

The collection view is given an array that contains the URLs, and so far, I have been downloading off the internet within `collection view cellforitematindexpath`

However, the view only becomes visible after all the cells have been loaded, and since each call to `collection view cellforitematindexpath` downloads an image, if 20 images are pulled off of URLs, it takes way to long.

What can I do to display the view, and THEN download the images, and then display them?

Hope I made myself understandable, if not, please ask!

Thanks!

C

Comment: Have you seen `SDWebImage`? Will make your life 100x easier: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Another option would be AFNetworking. AFNetworking has some categories on UIImageView that will do what you want: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use SDWebImage (as mention at comment above).
Another interesting side you could face out, that if image haven't load yet and user scroll view, it could be problems with `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath`, so it's better to download images throw `id <SDWebImageOperation>`.

Prepare for reuse will be something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    if (self.imageOperation)
        [self.imageOperation cancel];

    self.imageOperation = nil;
}
```

And load will be like this:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];    
self.imageOperation = [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                      options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                                     progress:nil
                                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                                        if (image)
                                        {
                                            self.imageView.image = image;
                                        }
                                    }];
```

Comment: Do I need to make my CollectionView a UICollectionReusableView? That means I need to get rid of my loadView method?

Comment: The method's described in the answer should reside in the UICollectionViewCell subclass, not the UICollectionView and yes you should by default use reusable cells.